# How to compare two object arrays by Id and build new array with combined properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const productsMaster = Immutable.fromJS([{
  "bathrooms": "2.5",
  "price": 309990,
  "name": "Costa Verde",
  "garages": {
    "config": null,
    "number": "2"
  },
  "stories": 1,
  "history": [{
    "date": "2017-09-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 309990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 309990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }, {
    "date": "2017-03-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 307990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }],
  "bedrooms": "3",
  "id": "41D0F85C-4798-465C-B5AA-F4B6F7F56901",
  "finishedSqFt": 2107,
  "isModel": false
}, {
  "bathrooms": "2",
  "price": 281990,
  "name": "La Mancha",
  "garages": {
    "config": null,
    "number": "2"
  },
  "stories": 1,
  "history": [{
    "date": "2017-09-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 281990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 281990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }, {
    "date": "2017-03-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 279990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }],
  "bedrooms": "3",
  "id": "A0D296AC-B5E8-4D21-9155-D2A0B4536B48",
  "finishedSqFt": 1826,
  "isModel": false
}, {
  "bathrooms": "2",
  "price": 289990,
  "name": "Madrid",
  "garages": {
    "config": null,
    "number": "2"
  },
  "stories": 1,
  "history": [{
    "date": "2017-09-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 289990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 289990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }, {
    "date": "2017-03-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 287990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }],
  "bedrooms": "3",
  "id": "5BE28BA0-DD4E-449B-8814-BBD9D44541B8",
  "finishedSqFt": 2005,
  "isModel": false
}, {
  "bathrooms": "3",
  "price": 349990,
  "name": "Residence 5",
  "garages": {
    "config": null,
    "number": "3"
  },
  "stories": 2,
  "history": [{
    "date": "2017-09-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 349990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 349990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }, {
    "date": "2017-03-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 349990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }],
  "bedrooms": "3",
  "id": "EE791214-023F-49BC-BB39-04707ACB35EE",
  "finishedSqFt": 2391,
  "isModel": false
}, {
  "bathrooms": "3",
  "price": 364990,
  "name": "Residence 6",
  "garages": {
    "config": null,
    "number": "3"
  },
  "stories": 2,
  "history": [{
    "date": "2017-09-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 364990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 364990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }, {
    "date": "2017-03-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 364990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }],
  "bedrooms": "4",
  "id": "0B8472E6-DE56-4E32-ADD0-39EA392DBE53",
  "finishedSqFt": 2579,
  "isModel": false
}, {
  "bathrooms": "2",
  "price": 259990,
  "name": "Santona",
  "garages": {
    "config": null,
    "number": "2"
  },
  "stories": 1,
  "history": [{
    "date": "2017-09-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 259990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }, {
    "date": "2017-06-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 259990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }, {
    "date": "2017-03-30T00:00:00",
    "closings": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "starts": {
      "qtr": 0,
      "total": 0
    },
    "price": 259990,
    "units": {
      "released": null,
      "available": null,
      "sold": null,
      "inventory": null
    }
  }],
  "bedrooms": "3",
  "id": "237CA02C-1C66-4182-8BEC-D66D6B2AF500",
  "finishedSqFt": 1601,
  "isModel": false
}])

const products = Immutable.fromJS([{
  "unitsSold": 5,
  "bestSeller": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "bestSeller"
  },
  "model": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "model"
  },
  "productId": "",
  "name": "",
  "auditPrice": 309990,
  "unitsPlanned": 5,
  "notAvailable": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "notAvailable"
  },
  "id": "E9273001-B2CB-4057-943D-0384ED5BC00D",
  "finishedSqFt": ""
}, {
  "unitsSold": 0,
  "bestSeller": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "bestSeller"
  },
  "model": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "model"
  },
  "productId": "",
  "name": "",
  "auditPrice": 280990,
  "unitsPlanned": 10,
  "notAvailable": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "notAvailable"
  },
  "id": "BEE1E6B1-968E-4A25-A74F-731B8CD15E17",
  "finishedSqFt": ""
}, {
  "unitsSold": 4,
  "bestSeller": {
    "checked": true,
    "label": "",
    "value": "bestSeller"
  },
  "model": {
    "checked": true,
    "label": "",
    "value": "model"
  },
  "productId": "",
  "name": "",
  "auditPrice": 292990,
  "unitsPlanned": 5,
  "notAvailable": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "notAvailable"
  },
  "id": "E1CB9E4F-B634-4043-B4D4-BAB441F47766",
  "finishedSqFt": ""
}, {
  "unitsSold": 2,
  "bestSeller": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "bestSeller"
  },
  "model": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "model"
  },
  "productId": "",
  "name": "",
  "auditPrice": 340990,
  "unitsPlanned": 3,
  "notAvailable": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "notAvailable"
  },
  "id": "EB0E0343-1BDD-4DD3-BA1A-CF0625F3CDF6",
  "finishedSqFt": ""
}, {
  "unitsSold": 2,
  "bestSeller": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "bestSeller"
  },
  "model": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "model"
  },
  "productId": "",
  "name": "",
  "auditPrice": 362990,
  "unitsPlanned": 2,
  "notAvailable": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "notAvailable"
  },
  "id": "41D0F85C-4798-465C-B5AA-F4B6F7F56901",
  "finishedSqFt": ""
}, {
  "unitsSold": 3,
  "bestSeller": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "bestSeller"
  },
  "model": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "model"
  },
  "productId": "",
  "name": "",
  "auditPrice": 261990,
  "unitsPlanned": 5,
  "notAvailable": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "notAvailable"
  },
  "id": "A0D296AC-B5E8-4D21-9155-D2A0B4536B48",
  "finishedSqFt": ""
}, {
  "unitsSold": "",
  "bestSeller": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "bestSeller"
  },
  "model": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "model"
  },
  "productId": "",
  "name": "",
  "auditPrice": "",
  "unitsPlanned": "",
  "notAvailable": {
    "checked": false,
    "label": "",
    "value": "notAvailable"
  },
  "id": "5BE28BA0-DD4E-449B-8814-BBD9D44541B8",
  "finishedSqFt": ""
}])

function combineProducts(productsMaster, products) {

  let _products = []
  productsMaster.forEach(item => {
    const _prod = products.find(x => x.get('id') === item.get('id'))

    _products.push({
      name: item.get('name'),
      id: item.get('id'),
      finishedSqFt: item.get('finishedSqFt') || '',
      auditPrice: _prod ? _prod.get('auditPrice') : 0,
      unitsPlanned: _prod ? _prod.get('unitsPlanned') : 0,
      unitsSold: _prod ? _prod.get('unitsSold') : 0,
      model: {
        label: '',
        value: 'model',
        checked: _prod ? _prod.getIn(['model', 'checked']) : false
      },
      bestSeller: {
        label: '',
        value: 'bestSeller',
        checked: _prod ? _prod.getIn(['bestSeller', 'checked']) : false
      },
      notAvailable: {
        label: '',
        value: 'notAvailable',
        checked: _prod ? _prod.getIn(['notAvailable', 'checked']) : false
      }
    })
  })
  return _products
}

const result = combineProducts(productsMaster, products)
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

I have a simple need to compare two object arrays by ID and merge properties together in a new array. I am using the same functions that I always use, A find function inside a forEach loop. But the outcome is not the desired result. Only 2 Ids are matching up to combine objects. The difference between this function and the others I use this logic for is I need the end result to be the same length as the master array.

Comment: When you are *combining* objects you will have less number of objects in the result, isn't it?

Comment: What do you do if both arrays have an object with the same ID?

Comment: well I should have the same number of objects as the master array. So I am not sure if I am even looking at this correctly, I have been stuck on this for couple of days.

Comment: they are supposed to have the same ID. The master array has the default data. If nothing is in the second array than it stays that way.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  Ok, you're merging properties from some auxiliary product list into your master (or a copy of your master)

Comment: yes correct. sorry I was having trouble explaining it. that is exactly what I need

Comment: Does it matter if the auxiliary product list is damaged in the process?

Comment: not at all, all i need is the end result

Comment: @texas697 It seems like its working to me. Only the first 3 elements in `productsMaster` have a matching id in `products`.  And the resulting length is the same length as `productsMaster`.  Why is the result "not the desired result"?

Comment: well if that is the case then I need to sleep more.